# How to insert a comma to the child comment construction in function.php?

Tags: comments

I insert the name of parent comment's author in child comment

```
   if( $comment->comment_parent )
    comment_author( $comment->comment_parent );
```

How to insert a comma to this construction in function.php?

Example,

```
if( $comment->comment_parent )
comment_author( $comment->comment_parent ) . ', ';
```

do not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comment_author` prints the author. It doesn’t return anything.

So if you do this:

```
if ( $comment->comment_parent )
    comment_author( $comment->comment_parent ) . ', ';
```

Then, what it really does is:

- check if comment has parent and if so:

  - print its author
  - get the result of function `comment_author` (which is empty) and concatenate it with string containing ', '
  - don’t do anything with that string

And what you want is this:

```
if ( $comment->comment_parent ) {
    comment_author( $comment->comment_parent );
    echo ', ';
}
```